# NSDateFormatter with T-Z Time format

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api

I got a string in T-Z format such as "2015-12-12T05:30:03.634Z" from Google server. How can I convert it to format `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` by `NSDateFormat`?

I've tried some codes below, but always got (null) in variable dte.

```
+(NSDate*)tzStrToDateTime:(NSString*)tzStr{
  NSLog(@"Convert tzStr: %@ ",tzStr);
  NSString *tzFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX";//2015-12-12T05:30:03.634Z
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:tzFormat];
  [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Taipei"]];
  NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:tzStr];
  NSLog(@"to Date: %@", dte);
  return dte;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

initial dateFormat is like

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Taipei"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-12-12T05:30:03.634Z"];
//Second Conversion
 [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSString *finalStr = [dateFormat StringFromdate:dte];
```

Comment: Why are you setting the timezone of the date formatter before calling `dateFromString:`? It will be ignored at that point since the date format and the date string specify its timezone.